# Docslist.find executing very slowly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I am using DocsList.find() and everything in my code is working just fine. The only issue is that it can take up to 90 seconds to find a file in the folder specified even when there are only two files in the folder!

I was hoping that someone might be able to suggest a method of speeding up the execution. Or, it may be that I have misunderstood the folder element of DocsList. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Oli

Sample Code:

```
function myFunction() {
var folder = DocsList.getFolderById("MYFOLDERID");
var lastrow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1').getLastRow();
var thissheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());

var i = 3;
while (i<= lastrow)
if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Add scores to sheets').getRange(i,6).getValue() < 1){

 var getfile = folder.find(thissheet.getSheetByName('Add scores to sheets').getRange(i,3).getValue())[0].getId();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getfile).getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(thissheet.getSheetByName('Add scores to sheets').getRange(i,5).getValue());

  if(cell.getValue() < thissheet.getSheetByName('Add scores to sheets').getRange(i,4).getValue()){
  cell.setValue(thissheet.getSheetByName('Add scores to sheets').getRange(i,4).getValue());
  }


  thissheet.getSheetByName('Add scores to sheets').getRange(i,6).setValue(1);
   i++ 
}

else {i++}

}
```

The code takes a score form the sheet 'Add scores to sheet', finds the file named in column C (an email address), locates the named range and sets the value providing that the current value is less than the new value. I am a Maths teacher - this is all run from a Google form quiz.

Comment: Have you timed which sections of the script are performing slowly as it may not be the `DocsList` call? (for example you are calling `getSheetByName` for the same sheet multiple times, each of these calls has a cost and you may be better specifying your 'Add scores to sheets' sheet as a variable at the beginning of the script to save some execution time)

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I'm still not sure that this is the issue. Have a look at my reply to Michael's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue, `Folder.find()` was taking around 40 seconds to scan a single folder and to return just one file.

A way much faster solution is to use `Folder.getFiles()` and loop on the resultset to get what you need..

For example, if you need to delete all files that have "DELETED" string in filename:

**[SLOW] folder.find()**

```
var files = folder.find("DELETE");
for(var x = 0; x < files.length; x++){
  files[x].removeFromFolder(folder)
}
```

**[FAST] folder.getFiles()**

```
var files = folder.getFiles();
for(var x = 0; x < files .length; x++){
  var fileName = files[x].getName();
  if(fileName.indexOf("DELETE") > - 1){
    files[x].removeFromFolder(folder)
  }
}
```

The second version, in our particular case scenario, took only 3 seconds to complete.

Comment: Such a good idea! Can't believe I didn't think to index before! Thanks for the brilliant reply!

Comment: Anyway find behaviour is very weird.. how could it take so much time to scan a single folder?!?!

Answer (score 0):

As the above comment says, you may want to start by limiting calls to getSheetByName.  If you declare a variable, like so:

```
var addScoresToSheetsSheet = 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Add scores to sheets')
```

And then use that variable name in your while loop, like this:

```
if(addScoresToSheetsSheet.getRange(i,6).getValue() < 1){

 var getfile = folder.find(addScoresToSheetsSheet.getRange(i,3).getValue())[0].getId();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getfile).getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(addScoresToSheetsSheet).getRange(i,5).getValue());

  if(cell.getValue() < addScoresToSheetsSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue()){
  cell.setValue(addScoresToSheetsSheet).getRange(i,4).getValue());
  }


  addScoresToSheetsSheet.getRange(i,6).setValue(1);
   i++ 
}
```

It not only makes the code more readable, but also will make it execute faster.  If this is not sufficient, then you may want to read the entire sheet into an array, and then execute your code on the array, as mentioned here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices#batchOperations

Comment: Thanks for your time and top tips. I will certainly call the sheet as a variable, although this seems to not be the issue. The getSheetByName is taking 0 seconds each time according to the execution transcript. It is the folder.find() element that is taking the time. Here is a copy of the transcript: http://snag.gy/xRHFA.jpg